# Weird image moving on html site

Tags: html, css, image, onclick

I'm making a web site and suddenly I ran into a problem. It's not huge, but I would like to fix it. On my site I have many images but there is a glitch. The images are "dragable". I mean when you click on a image and than move your mouse the images are being dragged. How can that be fixed?

http://nitidus-consto.kilu.org/

Comment: Can you show a site where images are not draggable for comparison?

Comment: That's normal browser behavior.

Comment: I know that it's normal, but how to remove it...

Comment: *Kheldar Umm.. If I would see one I would read the source, but I couldn't find anything on the web.

Comment: I don't know about others, but sites that try (stupidly) to prevent me from interacting with parts of it annoy me to no end. If you want to do Flash, do Flash. HTML and CSS are designed to be open and readable, and so you can access the pictures easily. I hope that's not your concern here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always like this.
Don't find anything weird in it.

Anyway this link can help you:

http://www.redips.net/firefox/disable-image-dragging/

you can use javascript to avoid the image dragging:

html file:

```
<!-- right image (dragging disabled) -->
<img src="image.png" onmousedown="if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault()">
```

javascript:

```
// register onLoad event with anonymous function
window.onload = function (e) {
var evt = e || window.event,// define event (cross browser)
    imgs,                   // images collection
    i;                      // used in local loop
// if preventDefault exists, then define onmousedown event handlers
if (evt.preventDefault) {
    // collect all images on the page
    imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    // loop through fetched images
    for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        // and define onmousedown event handler
        imgs[i].onmousedown = disableDragging;
    }
 }
 };

 // disable image dragging
 function disableDragging(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks again! I worked I just made a new .js file copy-pasted the code, linked it to the html and added the onmousedown and it works :).